# if condition doesnt work properly always go in false block

Tags: android

hi following is my code where i am trying to get server responce if status is equal to success i show success message and if failed show failed but all time it show failed message why it happen.please give me solution of it.
verify.java
i dont know is it execute true or false block of if condition

```
public class verifyotp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(Verifyotp.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("edituser", Uid));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("editotp", abc));
            JSONObject json = jpar.makeHttpRequest(URL_VERIFY_OTP, "POST", param);
            String sts=json.getString(TAG_status);
            Log.v(TAG,""+json.getString(TAG_status));
           if(sts=="succuss")
            {
                Log.v(TAG,"in success block");
                lflag=true;

            }
            else
           {
               lflag=false;

           }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "Exception at end :" + e.toString());
            //Log.e("TAG", "Error......!RecoverIt");
        } return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
        super.onPostExecute(Result);

            if(lflag==true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Verifyotp.this, "Successsss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Verifyotp.this, "Faileddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            pdialog.hide();
            pdialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

it doesnt set lflag true it always show failed message.the another problem is as follow

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is;
static JSONObject jObj;
static String json;
static JSONArray jarr;
private static final String TAG = "myAppSurun";
public static String alternateJSONString = "";
public static JSONArray alternateJSONArray = null;
// constructor
public JSONParser() {
    is = null;
    jObj = null;
    json = "";
    jarr = null;
}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            Log.v(TAG, "Param String :" + url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.v(TAG,"To the End of IF");

        }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            Log.v(TAG,"Param String :"+url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            Log.v(TAG,"To the End of ELSE");
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.v(TAG,"JS_PARSER : Server Response -"+json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Error in getting json string from response : A further try will be given to use json string "+e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object/Array And String
    try {

        if(json != null) {
            alternateJSONString = json;
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.v(TAG,"JS_PARSER : JSON Object Created Successfully Use Object instance");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"JS_PARSER : JSON String is blank trying one more time to parse JSON String");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        try{
        if(json != null) {
            Log.v(TAG,"JS_PARSER :  Object Parsing failed Trying for Array if no more logs followed by \" JS_PARSER \" use JSONParser.alternateJSONArray for JSON instance. ");
            alternateJSONArray = new JSONArray(json);
        }
        else {
            Log.v(TAG,"JS_PARSER : JSON String is blank trying one last time to parse JSON String if no more logs followed by \" JS_PARSER \" use JSONParser.alternateJSONString for JSON instance");
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            if(json !=null) {

                Log.v(TAG, "JS_PARSER : Array Parsing also failed if no more logs followed by \" JS_PARSER \" use JSONParser.alternateJSONString for backup JSON string for results");
            }
            else {
                Log.v(TAG, "JS_PARSER : Final try also failed Confirm server log for request error or follow following log trail"+e1);
            }
        }
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;


}
```

this is my jsonparser file 
if i entered wrong otp it will display me following response

```
   1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore V/myAppSurun﹕ To the End of IF
      10-01 11:19:11.207    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore V/myAppSurun﹕ JS_PARSER : Server Response -
        10-01 11:19:11.213    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore V/myAppSurun﹕ JS_PARSER :  Object Parsing failed Trying for Array if no more logs followed by " JS_PARSER " use JSONParser.alternateJSONArray for JSON instance.
      10-01 11:19:11.213    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore V/myAppSurun﹕ JS_PARSER : Array Parsing also failed if no more logs followed by " JS_PARSER " use JSONParser.alternateJSONString for backup JSON string for results
        10-01 11:19:11.224    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        10-01 11:19:11.227    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore W/System.err﹕ at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.Verifyotp$verifyotp.doInBackground(Verifyotp.java:85)
      10-01 11:19:11.227    1843-1904/com.example.surun.suruninfocore W/System.err﹕ at com.example.surun.suruninfocore.Verifyotp$verifyotp.doInBackground(Verifyotp.java:68)
```

Comment: use if(sts.equals("succuss")) instead of sts=="succuss" it will work

Comment: ==  check the instance not content, to compare content of string use equals() method

Comment: i have one more problem

Answer (score 3):

Use `equals` instead of `==` .Try this way .I hope it will works

> In Java, one of the most common mistakes meet is using == to
>   compare Strings. You have to remember, == compares the object
>   references, not the content.
>
> string1.equals(String target) compares the two strings based off of
>   the actual characters in the strings.

### Good Practice/Proper Way

```
if(sts.equals("succuss"))
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"in success block");
            lflag=true;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` comparison are always compare using  :

```
equals() OR equalsIgnoreCase()
```

Object comparison are always compare using :

```
==
```

In your case try to use :

```
if(sts.equals("succuss")) OR if(sts.equalsIgnoreCase("succuss"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are Comparing String so You should use

```
if(sts.equalsIgnoreCase("succuss"))
{
     lflag=true;
}
```

And it will give expected result.